# How to use select statement in procedure in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Why would my SQL throw an error like LEAVE with no matching label: tableList

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CountSignatures$$

CREATE PROCEDURE CountSignatures()
  BEGIN
     DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE signatureCount INT;
     DECLARE tableName CHAR(100);
     DECLARE tableList CURSOR FOR Select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema="LogData" and table_name like "%FAULT_20150320%";
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
     OPEN tableList;
     tableListLoop: LOOP
       SET done = FALSE ;
       FETCH tableList INTO tableName;
       IF done THEN
         LEAVE tableListLoop;
       END IF;
       ***select signatureCount := signatureCount + count(distinct signature) from tableList;*** Line giving syntax error
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE tableList;
  END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would generate that particular error, but this line is not correct:

```
signatureCount = signatureCount + Select count (distinct signature) from tableList;
```

If you want to update the variable, try:

```
set signatureCount = (signatureCount +
                      (select count(distinct signature)
                       from tableList));
```

However, you don't initialize the variable, so this will just produce `NULL` anyway.

Comment: @eggyal . . . You are 1000% correct.  I was thinking more about the lack of initialization rendering the logic useless -- even if it did run.

Answer (score 1):

*[leave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/leave.html) lable*:

> This statement is used to exit the flow control construct that has the
>   given label. If the label is for the outermost stored program block,
>   LEAVE exits the program.

In your code `tableList` is a cursor, you should leaved the `tableListLoop` not `tableList`, so try:

```
LEAVE tableListLoop;
```